# converting TS syntax to JSDOC

Tags: javascript, sveltekit

I am trying to convert a code snippet from TS to plain javascript jsdoc. Is there a good wiki that explains this ?

before

```
  import { SvelteKitAuth, type SvelteKitAuthConfig } from '@auth/sveltekit';
  import type { Provider } from '@auth/core/providers';
```

after:

```
 import { SvelteKitAuth  } from '@auth/sveltekit';
/** @type {import('@auth/sveltekit').SvelteKitAuthConfig} */
export let svelteKitAuthConfig 
/** @type {import('@auth/core/providers').Provider}; */
export let provider
```

I have error "unexpected token" when I try to reference provider

```
config: svelteKitAuthConfig = {
  providers: [
    Auth0Provider({
      id: 'auth0',
      name: 'Auth0',
      clientId: '-client-id-',
      clientSecret: '-client-secret-',
      issuer: 'https://dev-****.auth0.com/',  // <- remember to add trailing `/` 
      wellKnown: 'https://dev-****.auth0.com/.well-known/openid-configuration'
    }) as provider   <-- Error here
  ],
  secret: '-any-random-string-',
  debug: true,
  session: {
    maxAge: 1800 // 30 mins
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`as` is TypeScript syntax, it does not exist in JS. (Also `provider` is a value, not a type.)

You can try to use another `/** @type {...} */` annotation before the value you are trying to type. Possibly extract it to a separate `const` first.

Comment: That was helpful. I need to dig into Auth.js more. example : https://authjs.dev/reference/sveltekit